# speech recognizer not working in ios 13 background

Tags: ios, cordova, sfspeechrecognizer

I am trying to implement speech recognizer in iOS application using Cordova. I am using iOS 13.1. It is working when application is front. But not working when application moved to background.

I got the following error:

> 2020-01-21 15:30:41.549170+0530 Pro@Me[2212:613705] [Utility] +[AFAggregator logDictationFailedWithError:] Error Domain=kAFAssistantErrorDomain Code=1700 "(null)"
>   2020-01-21 15:30:41.553271+0530 Pro@Me[2212:613445] [aurioc] AURemoteIO.cpp:1590:Start: AUIOClient_StartIO failed (561145187)
>   2020-01-21 15:30:41.553429+0530 Pro@Me[2212:613445] [avae]            AVAEInternal.h:109   [AVAudioEngineGraph.mm:1544:Start: (err = PerformCommand(*ioNode, kAUStartIO, NULL, 0)): error 561145187
>   2020-01-21 15:30:41.556057+0530 Pro@Me[2212:613445] THREAD WARNING: ['SpeechRecognition'] took '42.260986' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.
>   2020-01-21 15:30:41.556959+0530 Pro@Me[2212:613445] startListening() recognitionTask error: Error Domain=kAFAssistantErrorDomain Code=1700 "(null)"

Suggest some solutions.

Comment: Why would you expect your app to be able to recognise speech when it isn't the active foreground app?

Comment: @Paulw11 I can see several use cases where one would want to do that. For example, a chat application that allow you to send text messages while in the background.

Comment: How would it be a good user experience for some chat program to be listening to you and transcribing your speech into a chat window when that app wasn't the foreground app on the screen? If I want to send text messages I would want to open the text message app to do so.

Comment: Yes. I want to convert speech to text in background

Answer (score 0):

Apple does not support speech recognition in the background. You will have to use an alternative solution in order to perform your task.

Quoted from [Source](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/53784#thread-message-202270):

> Apple has closed my issue with the following:
>
> We explicitly don't support speech recognition in the background currently.
>
> We consider this issue closed.  If you have any questions or concern regarding this issue, please update your report directly (http://bugreport.apple.com).
>
> Thank you for taking the time to notify us of this issue.
>
> Best Regards,
>
> Apple Developer Support
>
> Worldwide Developer Relations

Comment: Can you suggest any alternative to achive that?

Comment: That quote added on Dec 18, 2016 5:41 by apple .  Is there any solution now?

Comment: You may stream the audio from the device to use a third party speech recognition service, like google speech-to-text.